# Why ARP cache is not emptied as I except it to be?

Tags: linux, arp

I'm trying to empirically test the time an entry stays in the `ARP cache` table.

This time seems to be defined by `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_stale_time` file and by `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_timeout` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_interval` files for `garbage collector`.

As the values are respectively 60, 300 and 60 it should not exceed 420 seconds, should it?

Anyway it seems to stay much longer (if I don't miss something). Indeed What I am doing in order to verify that is to execute the following bash command:

```
while true; do date; sudo arp -n; sleep 30; done
```

and after more than 15 minutes the entry is still in the `ARP table`.

Please note that as I have read that the kernel can change timeout values based on positive feedback from higher level protocols, I didn't try to access a website during this time.

So my question is: why the entry is still referenced in the table after such a long time? What I am doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ask myself:

1. What ip address on the subnet is the arp table entry mapping a mac address for (i.e. which host does the entry point to)?
2. Is the arp table entry [persistent](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-add-or-remove-static-arp-entry-on-linux.html) or not (i.e. can I expect it to auto-purge from the arp table)?
3. Have I sniffed traffic through the relevant interface during the test interval (to find or not find evidence for arp remapping against the given ip address)?

Finally:

- How did I attempt to produce an entry in the arp table in a controlled manner, with the expectation of measuring its durability?

The answers gained through the first three questions will likely refine the testing procedure as given through the last question.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer. I'm going to answer the questions you asked:
1. The entry points to an other computer of my subnetwork
2. I would say no, since the only thing I have done was to ping the other computer. (But it seems to be false.)
3. In principle no.
Finally, as I said it in the answer 2, I produced the entry in the arp table by pinging the other computer of the subnetwork.
So the problem is probably that the table entry is persistent, but I don't see what else can be done in order to avoid that and refine the testing procedure...

Comment: The most likely answer in most cases is that the computers are communicating, thereby renewing the entry. You sniff to be able to rule that out (or get it confirmed). Fruitless it is to investigate arp without sniffing.

Comment: When I sniff with Wireshark I don't see any communication between the two computers. What can I conclude?

Comment: That it behaves in a manner which may appear similar to persistence. This can be due to it actually being set static or because your stack behaves that way, for example: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/address-resolution-protocol-arp/117398-qanda-arp-timeout-00.html